# How can I block clients that consistently hit the same unpredictable URLs

Tags: apache, ddos, fail2ban

My apache server goes down when a random client starts al lot of GET for same url. The problem is it happens with unpredictable url paths. With fail2ban i can ban a predetermined url but not prevent it for unknown url paths. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe you can ban clients that are getting too many 404 errors in a given time interval?  I think fail2ban could do that.

Comment: the urls are real, not 404

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Web Server, you should be able to scan your web server logs for GET requests and ban people who make too many of them within a specific time period. You just need to be careful to avoid banning legitimate users, so the frequency of allowable GET requests is something to fine tune carefully.

1. Create a new Jail Filter: `sudo nano /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/GETFlood.conf`
2. Define the regex you need for identifying GET requests based on the logs for your Web server. With a standard Apache access.log, it would be: `failregex = ^<HOST>.*\s"GET\s.*$`
3. Add an entry to your `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

   ```
   [getflood]
   enabled  = true
   action   = iptables-allports[name=getflood]
   filter   = getflood
   logpath  = /var/log/apache2/*access.log
   maxretry = 30
   findtime = 90
   bantime  = 604800
   ```

Here, we let any individual IP Address make up to 30 GET requests every 90 seconds. Again, without more details about your server, you'll need to play around with these timings to avoid banning legitimate users.